# biblatex: excluding shorthand entries from the main bibliography

Tags: sectioning, biblatex

I use the following coding for biblatex with verbose-ibid, sorry I still do not know how to include a file:

---

```
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,firstinits=true,sorting=nty,sortcites=true,useprefix=false,maxnames=6,backend=biber]{biblatex} % originally the style was verbose-ibid

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%put commas instead of periods after some elements of the title
%\usepackage{biblatex}%remove �in� in journal articles
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
\ifentrytype{article}{}{%
\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\printtext[parens]{% ADDED
\printlist{location}%
\iflistundef{publisher}
  {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
  {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
\printlist{publisher}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\usebibmacro{date}%
}\nopunct% ADDED
\newunit}
%for citing short forms
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
\printnames{labelname}%
\setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
% If article:
\ifentrytype{article}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printfield{volume}}{%
% If incollection:
\ifentrytype{incollection}{%
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \printtext[booktitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}}}{%
% Else:
\printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}}

\printshorthands

\printbibliography
```

---

I try to use shorthands for some of the books usually quoted in a shorthand form. This is the example for it:

```
@book{Eide.1994,
author = {Eide, T. and Hagg, T. and {Holton Pierce} and R. and Török, L.},
year = {1994},
title = {Fontes Historiae Nubiorum},
number = {I},
publisher = {University of Bergen, Department of Classics},
location = {Bergen},
shorthand = {FHN}
```

My problems are:

1. This title is repeated in the shorthand and in the bibliography. I wanted only in the shorthand.
2. I would like not to waste many pages. I would like something like:

Bibliography title at the top of the page. Then shorthands immediately after the title and after shorthands are finished, the normal bibliography.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your style modifications are unrelated to your actual problems. :-) That said, here's how to solve them:

1. To exclude entries with a `shorthand` field from the "normal" bibliography, define a corresponding bibcheck. See section 3.5.9 of the `biblatex` manual for details.
2. To typeset the bibliography and the list of shorthands as `\section*` instead of `\chapter*` in the `book`/`report` class, use the "subbibliography" heading and a custom-defined "subshorthands" heading. See section 3.5.7 of the manual for details.

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\defbibcheck{noshorthand}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\skipentry}%
}

\makeatletter
  \defbibheading{subshorthands}[\losname]{%
    \section*{#1}%
    \if@twoside\markright{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  shorthand = {Aut},
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibheading

\printshorthands[heading=subshorthands]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Other References},check=noshorthand]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

locksteps answer is way better, but there is another possibility **using keywords** for not printing entries with shorthand fields in the main bibliography:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  shorthand = {Aut},
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  keywords ={shorthand}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printshorthands
\printbibliography[title={Other References}, notkeyword=shorthand]

\end{document}
```

Which accomplishes what is desired concerning entries with shorthand fields in the main bibliography:

[image]

[image]